How can I stop the Geo Node particle system from falling through objects when collided?
I'm following this tutorial to create the particle collide simulation. Some of the particle did stop falling when particle is detected near the object, but most of them  still fall through:



You would either have to increase the minimum distance to count a collision (Less Than node) or create substeps within a frame (e.g. with a Repeat Zone). If your particles are too quick, 2 successive positions can go through a surface without being close enough to register it (according to your Less Than node).

Or use raycasting to check a path instead of discrete points.
